# How can I copy files which is not exists?

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I want to write .bat file, I have two folders which names are A and B. I have pictures on A , and I want to transfer them from A to B , But I want to transfer pictures which is not exists. Pictures names are 1.jpg 2.jpg ,,,,90.jpg How can I do that? Is it possible?

In folder A there is

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
...
40.jpg
```

In folder B there is

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
...
90.jpg
```

I just want to transfer 41.jpg,,,,,90.jpg but this code should be dynamic because file names are changed for the next time.

thanks

Comment: try to create one hash table for folder B image names ..and try to find image names of folder A in hash table if not exist ..do what ever u want(copy,move...ect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the pictures in A

```
for %%F in (A\*) do
```

then check whether they exist in B

```
if not exist "B\%%~nxF"
```

and copy them if they don't

```
copy /Y "%%F" B
```

In summary:

```
for %%F in (A\*) do if not exist "B\%%~nxF" copy /Y "%%F" B
```

That is, if I understood you correctly that you only want to copy all images from A that are not present already in B. Your question is a little confusing in that regard because it seem like you want to copy images from A to B that *don't* exist in A, which doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: thanks for asnwering , I will back soon after I tried it

Comment: @Joey I missed the transfer modified files, I mean if any files changed I want to transfer too, How can I detect them? any command to detect?

Comment: @user3086226: Use dbenham's answer then. Perhaps with slightly different options. Or just copy all files. It's not that overwriting a few dozen files is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Joey How can I write robocopy in for loop for every 1 second on batch file

Answer (score 3):

No batch script required - The ROBOCOPY command is all you need:

```
robocopy A B /xc /xn /xo /xx /njh /njs /ns /nc /ndl
```

All of the options beginning with `/n` simply control what info is logged to the screen. The options I chose result in only the copied filenames being listed.

Comment: I was searching for the correct flags to pass to `xcopy` but then got sidetracked by work again ;-). Agreed, using a tool that does exactly what they need already is probably best.

Comment: Hi, I want to use it for every 1 second so I must write batch file , how can I write it